# Math symbol doesn't work properly

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Something quite strange. Why I have as a result of the following formula:

```
\begin{equation}
\omega=\lambda_{1}\Sigma^{-1}\bf{1}+\lambda_{2}\Sigma^{-1}\mu
\end{equation}
```

a black square instead the sigma symbol? in the first part is ok. I am becoming a bit crazy trying to find out the error. I tried everything, to separate, to isolate, to write the formula with double $$ rather than \begin{equation}, packages loaded are the normal ones, etc... Any other symbol works perfectly but with \Sigma is quite weird, this is what I got no matter the way you try to write the formula.

[image]

Thanks for your support!

Comment: `\bf` should never be used in latex but if you do use it the syntax would be `{\bf 1}` but use `\mathbf{1}`

Comment: Your usage of `\bf{}` is wrong, it should be `\mathbf{}`. A long time ago in a galaxy far far away it should *have* been `{\bf }`, but not any more. I suspect what's happened is now everything after `\bf` is in the bold font and `\Sigma`'s place in the bold font encoding is taken by the square

Comment: You're right. My fault. Sorry for  the inconvenience :(

Comment: @José No need to apologise - not an inconvenience - it's always good to be able to correct these errors which are easy to make :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this code:

```
\begin{equation}
\omega=\lambda_{1}\Sigma^{-1} \mathbf{1}+\lambda_{2}\Sigma^{-1}\mu
\end{equation}
```

returns this output:

[image: correct output for equation]

Only the `\bf` command was exchanged with `\mathbf`.

Comment: Bufff!!! Yes, I admit it. Big mistake. My fault given that I am not so newcomer to latex as it could be ;) Sorry for the inconvenience.